STM32 F4 - UART overrun errok clor flag never gets cleared
I am starting development on an STM32F4 (using a Weact Black Pill), and am running into a problem with UART error flags. Note that for various reasons I am not using HAL at all, apart from the register definitions in the STM header files.
It's got three flags basically - parity, framing and overrun. Using UART1, What I am finding is that if the FIFO overrun flag (ORE) gets set, it stays set, doesn't get cleared again.
The manual says "The ORE bit is reset by a read to the USART_SR register followed by a USART_DR
register read operation".
The IRQ handler code does this:
volatile U32
        regSR = rxB->uartInfo.baseReg->SR;  //  read status register
volatile U8
        b = rxB->uartInfo.baseReg->DR;  //  read the receiver data

....

if ((regSR & USART_SR_ORE) == USART_SR_ORE) //  log fifo overrun error
    rxB->errorFlags |= RX_OVERRUNERROR;

The rxB->... stuff just stores peripheral register information for the specific UART - the same code is used on different UARTs. In this case rxB->uartInfo.baseReg->SR means USART1->SR, for instance. The peripheral registers are all defined as volatile.
What I don't get is why the read into regSR followed by the data read from the DR reg doesn't clear the overrun flag, but it doesn't. Once set it stays set until a complete UART reinitialisation. The code basically all works fine - until the ORE flag gets set.
UPDATE:
Now sorted following some code rearrangement, however not clear why the rearrangement made any difference. Need to look closely at how the compiler optimised the code.

What I don't get is why the read into regSR followed by the data read from the DR reg doesn't clear the overrun flag, but it doesn't.  How do you know? How exactly do you test this?

"What I am finding is that if the FIFO overrun flag (OVE) gets set, ..." - Sloppy description. It's a USART rather than a UART. There's no FIFO; you made that up. The error bit is named ORE, and not OVE. You need to provide a minimal, reproducible example, rather than just three statements. Your word descriptions do not seem accurate. "Once set it stays set ..." - That's your conclusion rather than an observation. Provide (raw) facts rather than your interpretation.

Declaring the local variable that receives the copy of the register as volatile is meaningless.  You need to declare the pointer as pointer-to-volatile not the copy of it.

Tom V: Yes, thanks, I know that, I was just getting desperate and trying volatile everywhere to see if it made any difference, and it didn't, not surprisingly. It had volatile in there when I copied it. wek: by looking with the debugger, solved it actually by code rearranging, need to look at how the compiler optimised the code. sawdust: thanks in a way for your comment, but if you just want to pick holes, why say anything at all? However (a) It's a one entry fifo in effect, (b) OVE was a mistype, (c) it's a UART if you don't output the clock.
